# Does this result for two vectors generalize to larger sets?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have linearly independent two-dimensional column vectors $\mathbf{x}_1=\left[{a}\atop{b}\right],\mathbf{x}_2=\left[{c}\atop{d}\right]$. Now let the "weight" of vector $\mathbf{x}_1$ be $p_1\in(0,1)$, and the "weight" of vector $\mathbf{x}_2$ be $p_2=1-p_1$.  One can show (using straightforward but tedious arithmetic) that the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}=p_1\mathbf{x}_1\mathbf{x}_1^T+p_2\mathbf{x}_2\mathbf{x}_2^T$ are the same as the eigenvalues of a $2\times2$ matrix $\mathbf{B}$ whose $(i,j)$-th element $B_{i,j}=\sqrt{p_ip_j}\mathbf{x}_i^T\mathbf{x}_j$.  In fact, the restriction for weights summing to one is unnecessary.

I am wondering if this generalizes to $n$ linearly independent $n$-dimensional vectors $\{\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots\mathbf{x}_n\}$ with corresponding weights $\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$, where, say $\sum_{i=1}^np_i=1$.  Thus, $\mathbf{A}=\sum_{i=1}^np_i\mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_i^T$ and $\mathbf{B}$ is defined as above.  I think that their eigenvalues are the same (and confirm this belief with a few numerical experiments).  I also feel that this should be a pretty simple proof, but I can't seem to figure out where to get started.  Any ideas/hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be seen by writing $A$ with respect to the basis $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, or equivalently conjugating using an invertible matrix. Let $X$ be the matrix whose $i^{\rm th}$ column is $\sqrt{p_i}x_i$. Then
$$
  A(\sqrt{p_i}x_i)=\sqrt{p_i}\sum_j p_jx_jx_j^Tx_i
    =\sum_j(\sqrt{p_ip_j}x_j^Tx_i)(\sqrt{p_j}x_j)
    =\sum_jB_{ji}\sqrt{p_j}x_j.
$$
Thus $AX=XB$. Assuming the $x_i$ are linearly independent and all $p_i>0$, $X$ is invertible so $A=XBX^{-1}$. Thus $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues.